# How to obtain IMPORTED_LOCATION according to the "current" configuration?

Tags: cmake

In my project I use a dynamic library engine.dll.
engine dll is compiled once for debug configuration and once for release configuration.

Here is how I declare the imported target:

```
add_library(engine SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(
    engine
    PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/Debug/engine.dll"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/Release/engine.dll"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELWITHDEBINFO
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/Release/engine.dll"
)
```

I would like to copy engine.dll to the relevant output directory. for this purpose, I want to query its IMPORTED_LOCATION property according to the build config.

```
get_target_property(
    dynamic_library_target_imported_location # out value
    engine
    IMPORTED_LOCATION
)
```

But this fails. so how can I have `dynamic_library_target_imported_location` contain the correct location according to the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT2:** If you still persist on not using **generator expressions** which I **highly recommend** as **they are safe and always behave in a well defined matter.** Then you should instead of `IMPORTED_LOCATION` use the property [`LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LOCATION.html). However you should try to obtain this property **at the latest time possible** as you shouldn't do anything that might change the imported targets location.

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment I guess I should clarify what the **generator expression** does:

```
$<IF:$<CONFIG:Release,RelWithDebInfo>:Release,Debug>
```

- If you build with `Release` or `RelWithDebInfo` config the generator expression will expand to:

```
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/Release/engine.dll
```

- If you build with anything other than the configs above mentioned then:

```
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/Debug/engine.dll
```

**NOTE:** This is exactly what you wanted to achieve with the `IMPORTED_LOCATION`.

Since you already know the location of the imported library beforehand, there is no need to set/get the property. **You can just use the generator expression to do exactly what you want.**

---

For installing targets I would recommend: [file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#get-runtime-dependencies) It is not recommended outside installs as they mention in the documentation.

If by output directory you mean build directory then why not just straight up copy it via a post-build command (or without) using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)? e.g.

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin_jit/$<IF:$<CONFIG:Release,RelWithDebInfo>:Release,Debug>/engine.dll
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/engine.dll)
```

Comment: The problem seem to be the querying of the the IMPORTED_LOCATION property, not the actual copying command once you have it.

Comment: @EladMaimoni I understand that, but you already know where the imported library is, so by using the generator expressions as outlined in the example - you can easily switch between the debug/release folder.